# How to use Modal Object preserved in a constructor of a class and call it from a different method?

Tags: c#, json, methods, dependency-injection, constructor

C# Programming is new for me and I'm trying to deserialize a Json file and use it as the class object.

I have a modal class Configmodal.cs This maps with the key-value pair of the json file.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JSParse
{
public  class ConfigModel
{
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("system")]
    public string System { get; set; }
}
}
```

This is the main file Program.cs which calls two methods Serialiser() and RetrieveValues().

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ParseJson pjs = new ParseJson();
        pjs.Serializer();


        //Don't know what parameter should be passed here too 
        GetJson gjson = new GetJson();
        gjson.RetrieveValues();

    }
}
```

Parsing of Json is fine and here is the code:

```
public class ParseJson
{
    public void Serializer()
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText(@"config.json");
        ConfigModel objConfig = 
           JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConfigModel(json);

        GetJson gj = new GetJson(objConfig);
    }
}
```

But I am unable to use this objConfig in a new method RetrieveJson of class Getjson.cs And here is the incomplete code:

```
 public class GetJson
{
    private readonly ConfigModel _ConfigModel;

    public GetJson(ConfigModel configModel)
    {
        _ConfigModel = configModel;
    }

    public void RetrieveValues()
    {
        //I've no idea how to call _ConfigModel of a constructor
        // and use those username, password in this method              
    }
}
```

Please help me out in performing two things which I've mentioned in the comment section of both methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say:

Change `ParseJson` class to:

```
public class ParseJson
{
  public GetJson Serializer()
  {
    var json = File.ReadAllText(@"config.json");
    ConfigModel objConfig = 
       JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConfigModel(json);

    return new GetJson(objConfig);
  }
```

}

And then change `GetJson` class

```
public class GetJson
{
  private readonly ConfigModel _ConfigModel;

  public GetJson(ConfigModel configModel)
  {
    _ConfigModel = configModel;
  }

  public ConfigModel RetrieveValues()
  {
    return _ConfigModel;          
  }
}
```

And change the main to:

```
class Program
{

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    ParseJson pjs = new ParseJson();
    GetJson gjson = pjs.Serializer();

    ConfigModel cf = gjson.RetrieveValues();
    //cf.Username and other members

    //OR you can have:  ConfigModel cf = pjs.Serializer().RetrieveValues();
  }
}
```

But I don't really see why you created so many classes.